# Replace keyboard input with scanning QR code

Tags: input, keyboard, scanning

I have **ticketing system** that I use for ***students*** who do consultation with their teachers. The system is working right now, the teacher need to input ticket number which is generated by students.

I want to change the way, I want the ticket number is shown as QRCode, and what the teacher need to do just scan the `QRCode` thru the camera of their laptop. So it's like replace the way they input the ticket number, from typing the ticket number to just scan the `QRCode`.

Comment: Ok, so what you need here is how to create QR code right?, if so which language you are using to generate the above feature

Comment: If you are using Ruby on Rails for the above feature, you can use rqrcode gem https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode, its very easy to implement

Comment: There are many other gems like the above you can take any one of that

Comment: we have successfully done for generate the qrcode, but what we need is, there is a field to input ticket number that we usually do just type the ticket number and enter, but since the ticket number is quite long and complicated, we want just scan the qrcode when the cursor is in the field, once the qr code is scanned by the web cam, it's automatically input the ticket number+enter and process

Comment: I don't know if my explanation is clear enough, sorry for my bad english

Comment: no I understand, yeah you can use that QR Scanner to scan your QR code and write according logic that it should be filled up the textbox

Comment: Its like, whenever you are scanning the QRCode that QR should contains url with query string of your ticket value, so after it was read a page will open with input box and all... based on that query string we will fill up the textbox(input field)

Comment: Is this making sense

Comment: sounds make sense, sorry to ask a lot of things, does it mean that we also have to build the QR scanner web based?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is with old-fashioned barcodes.
If the ticket number is short enough (up to 14 digits), you can format it as a EAN13 barcode (13 digits + control).

- The number conversion is trivial to make (just Google  "generate EAN13" + your programming language)
- EAN13 barcodes can be rendered as text with this TTF font: http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/EAN-13/
- Almost every QR reader understand linear barcodes
- You can get a Barcode Scanner Gun for 25$. They are plugged via USB, detected as USB keyboards, they input scanned codes as if you typed them and they are fast as hell!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a scanner soft keyboard. It scans the barcode / qr and set the result in input the same like you typed it.
In example this keyboard

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikosoft.nikokeyboard

It has the config option to scan and automatically send an Enter keyboard event.
I successfully use it on a telegram bot to similar functionality and I think is a very simple solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).